# Django/python - boolean checking if id in list of IDs returning false even though it's there?

Tags: python, django

I am working on the views file for my django project. There is a POST method that checks if an ID is in a list of IDs, but for some reason it's returning false, saying that the posted ID is not in the list. I can see very clearly that it's there. Here is the method:

```
        if response.POST.get("followUser"):
            userToFollowID = response.POST.get("followUser")
            listOfFollowedUsers =  list(userFollowing.objects.filter(username=userInfo.id).values_list('followingList', flat=True))
            print(userToFollowID)
            print(listOfFollowedUsers)
            print(userToFollowID in listOfFollowedUsers)
            if userToFollowID not in listOfFollowedUsers:
                print("we are here?")
                # t = userFollowing(username = userInfo, followingList = User.objects.get(id=userToFollowID))
                # t.save()
```

There's a lot of print statements and jargon, but basically it's supposed to check the POSTed ID and see if it's in the current users list. If the ID is not in the list, it goes into the method and it's supposed to create the database entry. This is the output from the print statements:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjSMb.png)

So the POSTed ID in this case is 6, the current user is following [6, 6] (supposed to have unique IDs but will fix afterwards) yet the code `print(userToFollowID in listOfFollowedUsers` returns `false` even though it should be True. We get into the if statement and it prints `we are here?` even though it shouldn't.

I'm probably doing something dumb but I can't see what the solution is.

Comment: The value in `POST` is a string, your list contains ints.

Comment: @deceze that was it, thank you! I hadn't realized POST methods returned strings.